# Splitting a polygon into separate polygons defined by a table of polygons

Tags: postgis, intersection, splitting, well-known-text

I am attempting to split an incoming polygon (IN WKT) into separate polygons based on the UK local authority boundaries, so that each returned polygon intersects with a local authority

For example, the incoming polygon is defined: `POLYGON((478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243,478104.0979036873 206470.69626820603,478159.97758179373 206446.08260046865,478170.2887128729 206477.01599370615,478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243))`

The table which the boundaries has a geometry column of wkb_geometry.

I cant seem to get the syntax correct.

Latest attempt is as follows:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243,478104.0979036873 206470.69626820603,478159.97758179373 206446.08260046865,478170.2887128729 206477.01599370615,478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243))'),27700), "boundaries"."wkb_geometry") 
FROM   "boundaries" 
WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243,478104.0979036873 206470.69626820603,478159.97758179373 206446.08260046865,478170.2887128729 206477.01599370615,478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243))'),27700), "boundaries"."wkb_geometry");
```

but that returns nothing.

Comment: Am I guessing correctly that your boundaries are `LINESTRING`s? Are you certain that the exemplary polygon actually intersects any of the boundaries?

Comment: The boundaries are MutliPolygons in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I need more sleep!

The query was correct, the table of geometries was in the wrong projection!

After reprojection the final query was:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Intersection(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243,478104.0979036873 206470.69626820603,478159.97758179373 206446.08260046865,478170.2887128729 206477.01599370615,478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243))'),27700),  "boundaries"."wkb_geometry")) from "boundaries" where ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243,478104.0979036873 206470.69626820603,478159.97758179373 206446.08260046865,478170.2887128729 206477.01599370615,478122.39184592455 206499.30134152243))'),27700), "boundaries"."wkb_geometry")
```

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.